# 1 laptop 2 monitors display not detecting third

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an Acer laptop.
I am using Windows 10.
I've been extending my work to 2nd monitor (Samsung).
Now I want to add a 3rd monitor (also Samsung).
I bought a HDMI splitter, but cant get it to work.
The 3rd monitor is a just duplicate of the 2nd.
It wont extend and the display settings only pick up 1 & 2, not 3.
I do not have a docking station.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Splitters do not create a new desktop, they merely allow the same signal to be passed to two destinations. Without a lot more detail we cannot say whether your computer is actually capable of running three external displays if cabled correctly - many aren't.

Comment: Do you think a docking station will help? I dont want to buy one if its not gonna work...

Comment: We don't have sufficient information.